# Block access to specific URL

Tags: java, glassfish

I have several java war applications hosted in a glassfish, some of then exposing web services. I need a way to block access to an specific application without blocking the entire access to server by firewall, that is, blocking access to http://server.com:8080/app1/start?somestuffs, for instance. Is there any glassfish config for this?

Answer (score 1):

You could put Apache in front of your glassfish server (let it listen on `127.0.0.1` only), forward requests with `mod_proxy_ajp` and configure access/redirect rules in Apache.

It's certainly not the prettiest or fastest solution, but it works.